# Who to award the bounty to?

Tags: discussion, bounty

[This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1061754/dual-booting-everytime-windows-boots-it-increases-the-scrolling-speed-of-the-m), WinEunuuchs2Unix has written the best answers and put the most effort, but nothing seems to work

Bernard Wei, a very smart answer, I really wished it would work, I thought it would work, it did not.

Fabby, watched all the solutions fail, gave the simplest solution, his solution works, honestly I think it's the only one that works.

Can I give WinEunuuchs2Unix  the bounty and accept fabby's answer? Should I open multiple bounties and award each of them something? Can I accept WinEunuuchs2Unix even though his answer did not solve the problem? Him and wei wasted time and energy trying to come up with very smart answers, it's unfair not to give them anything.

I have less than 24 hours to decide. I know that points mean nothing, at the end of the day we want to help each other but still.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can and it's a bit of a trick but WinEunuuchs2Unix deserves the bounty for all the work he put into it.

- Accept WinEunuuchs2Unix's answer, press "yes" to awarding your bounty, then accept Fabby's as the truth 25 hours later.
- If you would accept Fabby's now, that would be totally unfair to WinEunuuchs2Unix

**However,** It's completely up to you what you do with your rep and I'm just posting a personal and subjective opinion on what I would do.

### Disclaimers:

- I'm Fabby!  **:-)**
- I'm going to ping WinEunuuchs2Unix in chat and ask him to give his opinion here as well, but it'll take another 14 hours before he's back on-line again.

Comment: I'll do exactly what you said

Comment: You're a very honourable person...  **:-)**